# Writing An UPDATE statement using CONCAT

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have an update to make through PMA. It seems simple but might not be. I have attached an image of the DB table and relevant fields.

[image]
This is a DB table with some 90000 records. Some of the records in the "alias" column are exactly the result I need. For example, in the image, id's 743971, 743961 and 743951 are perfect. I am looking to update the 'alias' column with the matching number from the ID column, joined by a hyphen, and in lowercase. For example - in the image..the second record needs an alias update from just "ponder" to become "ponder-743981".

Is there a way to do an UPDATE with CONCAT, that can ignore the correct records, update the incorrect ones. (Ignore the first ID in that image, no alias records are blank.) Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: There is a way,but thats a really bad way to store data in a db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will only update incorrect alias columns

```
update mytable set alias = concat(lower(replace(imgtitle,' ','-')),'-',id)
where alias <> concat(lower(replace(imgtitle,' ','-')),'-',id)
```

but do you need to save the alias column at all?

```
select * , concat(lower(replace(imgtitle,' ','-')),'-',id) alias
from mytable
```

Comment: Thanks, Fuzzy Tree, that works perfectly, for some of the fields. except as I look through the imgtitle column, there are ampersands, commas, etc. Instead of replacing all those, is there a way we can change your query to just simply append "-" and "id" to the end of whatever data is already in the alias field, except for those that already match that pattern, of course. ?

Comment: @decaye change the `set` part to `set alias = concat(alias,'-',id)`